# UIActionSheet destructive button missing background

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, uiactionsheet

I have a `UIActionSheet` that I'm conditionally adding buttons to. If there are a lot of buttons (more so for portrait view), the destructive button detaches from the action sheet (as expected) to allow the items to scroll. The thing that is not right, is it does not have a background to it.

[image: iOS7 screenshot]

```
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:nil 
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle: nil
                                    destructiveButtonTitle:@"Changed my mind"
                                         otherButtonTitles:MAILBUTTON, BOOKMARKSBUTTON, CLEARCOOKIESBUTTON, nil];


if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    [sheet addButtonWithTitle:CAMERABUTTON];
}

sheet.tag = ACTION_SHEET;

if ([UIPrintInteractionController isPrintingAvailable])
{
    [sheet addButtonWithTitle:PRINTBUTTON];
}   

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([prefs boolForKey:BUMP_ENABLED_KEY] == YES)
{
    [sheet addButtonWithTitle:BUMPRECEIVEBUTTON];
    if ([prefs boolForKey:BUMP_ALLOW_SENDING_KEY] == YES)
        [sheet addButtonWithTitle:BUMPSENDBUTTON];
}

[sheet addButtonWithTitle: @""];
[sheet setCancelButtonIndex: sheet.numberOfButtons - 1];

[sheet showInView:self.view];
```

It looks fine in portrait mode, the destructive button has a background. If I add a lot more buttons though, it has the same behavior seen above.

Comment: Have the same issue. Did you ever find a less hacky solution? Thanks.

Comment: @anas No, I stuck with this solution. We've tested on multiple devices and different OS versions several times and have not ran into an issue though. The next best thing will be for Apple to resolve the bug, IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, it's a bit hacky. First I check if it's landscaped and that there are more than 5 buttons. When there are 6 or more, that's when it changes to a scrolling action sheet and that's when the problem occurs. If all that is true, I set the title to an empty string, with a space

```
[sheet setTitle: @" "];
```

This gives the white background to the button, but it leaves us with a big empty white space above, given you don't want a title.

To fix this, in `willPresentActionSheet`, I slide down the backdrop

```
        if (actionSheet.title)
        {
            if ([actionSheet.title.trim isEqualToString: @""])
            {
                CGRect backdropFrame = [[[actionSheet subviews] objectAtIndex: 0] frame];
                backdropFrame.origin.y += 45;
                backdropFrame.size.height -= 55;
                [[[actionSheet subviews] objectAtIndex: 0] setFrame: backdropFrame];
            }
        }
```